# SqlAlchemy auto increment composite key for every new combination

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have a scenario to iterate up `session_number` column for related `user_name`. If a user created a session before I'll iterate up the last `session_number` but if a user created session for the first time `session_number` should start from 1. I tried to illustrate on below. Right now I handle this by using logic but try to find more elegant way to do that in SqlAlchemy.

```
id - user_name - session_number
1      user_1             1
2      user_1             2
3      user_2             1
4      user_1             3
5      user_2             2
```

Here is my python code of the table. My database is PostgreSQL and I'm using alembic to upgrade tables. Right now it continues to iterate up the `session_number` regardless `user_name`.

```
class UserSessions(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_sessions'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    session_number = db.Column(db.Integer, Sequence('session_number_seq', start=0, increment=1))
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    last_edit = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    __table_args__ = (
        db.UniqueConstraint('username', 'session_number', name='_username_session_number_idx_'),
    )
```

I've searched on the internet for this situation but those were not like my problem. Is it possible to achieve this with SqlAlchemy/PostgreSQL actions?

Comment: You could possibly use a hybrid property, where the return value is the `count` of the user_name? https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/hybrid.html

Comment: Do I need to count of user_name? Did you mean session_number?

Comment: Do you actually need a value of `session_number` anywhere during the execution? Or would you just like to have/use it at some point later?

Comment: Do you need to store this value or can it be generated on retrieval?

Comment: @rfkortekaas yes I do actually. This is an illustration of the real problem but the scenario is the same.

Comment: I was meaning that if you count rows all rows for a given user_name, then the count+1 is the current session number for that user.

Answer (score 0):

*First, I do not know of any "pure" solution for this situation by using either SqlAlchemy or Postgresql or a combination of the two.*

Although it might not be exactly the solution you are looking for, I hope it will give you some ideas.

If you wanted to calculate the `session_number` for the whole table without it being stored, i would use the following query or a variation of thereof:

```
def get_user_sessions_with_rank():
    expr = (
        db.func.rank()
        .over(partition_by=UserSessions.username, order_by=[UserSessions.id])
        .label("session_number")
    )
    subq = db.session.query(UserSessions.id, expr).subquery("subq")
    q = (
        db.session.query(UserSessions, subq.c.session_number)
        .join(subq, UserSessions.id == subq.c.id)
        .order_by(UserSessions.id)
    )
    return q.all()
```

Alternatively, I would actually add a `column_property` to the model compute it on the fly for each instance of `UserSessions`. it is not as efficient in calculation, but for queries filtering by specific user it should be good enough:

```
class UserSessions(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user_sessions"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    last_edit = db.Column(db.DateTime)

# must define this outside of the model definition because of need for aliased
US2 = db.aliased(UserSessions)
UserSessions.session_number = db.column_property(
    db.select(db.func.count(US2.id))
    .where(US2.username == UserSessions.username)
    .where(US2.id <= UserSessions.id)
    .scalar_subquery()
)
```

In this case, when you query for `UserSessions`, the `session_number` will be fetched from the database, while being `None` for newly created instances.